# Encoding two vectors in a function

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Hey I'm writing a function that takes two `std::vector<std::string>` and returns a third `std::vector<std::string>`.

The function is going to encode the two vectors together and create the 3rd vector.

I'm currently debugging this to find out why it's not working, and I keep getting:  `vector subscript out of range`. As far as I can tell it's crashing at this line:

```
if (file2[i].size() < file1[i].size())
```

Can I use `size()` to get the size of the element at `i`?

```
std::vector<std::string> Encode(std::vector<std::string> &file1,
                                std::vector<std::string> &file2)
{
    std::vector<std::string> file3;
    std::string temp;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < file1.size(); i++) {
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < file1[i].size(); x++) {
            if (file2[i].size() < file1[i].size()) {
                for (unsigned int t = 0; t < file2[i].size(); t++) {
                    file3[i][x] = (int)file1[i][x] + (int)file2[i][t];
                }
            } else if (file2[i].size() > file1[i].size()) {
                file3[i][x] = (int)file1[i][x] + (int)file2[i][x];
            }

            if (file3[i][x] > 126) {
                file3[i][x] = file3[i][x] % 127;
            } else {
                file3[i][x] = file3[i][x] + 32;
            }
        }
    }
    return file3;
}
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: First guess, there are fewer strings in `vector` file2 than in `vector` file1. You only check the bounds on file1, and not file2. It is safer to use the `std::vector::at` operator. It will throw an out-of-bounds exception.

Comment: If `file2` has fewer elements then `file1`, `file2[i]` will go out of bounds once the outer loop reaches past the end of `file2`.

Comment: Any idea how then I would get it to loop back to the start?

Comment: I wanted them to iterate to file1's size because I want file 2 to loop back to the beggining if it is shorter than file 1's size.

Comment: Use separate counters or use the modulo operator.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be very much inclined to simplify by factoring.  At the lowest layer is a `combine` function to combine two `char`s into one:

```
char combine(char a, char b)
{
    char result = a+b;
    if (result > 126)
        return result % 127;
    return result+32;
}
```

The next level up would be to iterate through each of the letters in two strings of possibly different sizes.  The algorithm works for differing length strings by "recycling" through the shorter string.

```
std::string mix(const std::string &first, const std::string &second)
{
    unsigned len1 = first.length();
    unsigned len2 = second.length();
    if (len1 < len2)
        return mix(second, first);
    std::string result;
    // if the strings are of different lengths, first is now the longer
    unsigned j=0;
    for (unsigned i=0; i < len1; ++i, ++j) {
        if (j >= len2)
            j = 0;
        result.push_back(combine(first[i], second[j]));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Finally, the combination of the `vector` of `string` is much simpler:

```
std::vector<std::string> Encode(const std::vector<std::string> &file1,
                                const std::vector<std::string> &file2)
{
    std::vector<std::string> file3;

    assert(file1.size() == file2.size());
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < file1.size(); i++) {
        file3.push_back(mix(file1[i], file2[i]));
    }
    return file3;
}
```

Note that the code currently uses an `assert` to assure that the two `vector`s are the same length, but this is probably an artificial constraint.  Real code should either assure that they are the same length or do something else to handle that case.  Since it's not clear what your function is intended to do, I've left it to you to decide how to handle it, but with the `assert` as a placeholder to remind you that it does need to be addressed.

Finally, some driver code using C++11:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> english{"one", "two", "three", "four"};
    std::vector<std::string> spanish{"uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro"}; 

    auto result = Encode(english, spanish);

    std::copy(result.begin(), result.end(), 
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Note, too that I've used `push_back` to append to the end of the strings and `const` declarations for the passed strings.

Comment: Hey everything looks good, I tried looking around and couldn't figure out what (mix(file1[i], file2[i])); meant?

Comment: @Cellery72: `mix` is the name I gave to the function that mixes two strings together, so `mix(file1[i], file2[i])` simply calls that function with the two strings from the two `vectors`.  The source code for `mix` is given in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try these three sets of inputs: 
1. file1 is bigger than file2
2. file2 is bigger than file1
3. file1 is equal to file2 in size.
Let us know the cases when the error was reproduced and when it was not.
I think by this stage you will solve the problem by yourself. 
If not, 
write contents of the (smallest possible) file1 and file2 that reproduced the error.

Answer (score -1):

Some problems enumerated:

-You are **assuming that file1 and file2 have the same size or at least that file1 has size <= file2** (in the other case would cause invalid memory access in line `if (file2[i].size() < file1[i].size()) {`) and are not checking in the function for that. At least add an assert statement or a checking.
-You are initializing file3 **empty**, and are indexing later in the function.
-The other problem is what happen when file1[i] and file2[i] have the same length, this option is not cover in the if-else, the cover options are < and > but not ==.
-You are accessing invalid memory with statements like `file3[i][x]`, because the strings in `file3[i]` are initialized empty, for that, don't contain any character.

This is the more close that i can get without known the exact steps of the encode algorithm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

using namespace std;

std::vector<std::string> Encode(std::vector<std::string> &file1,
    std::vector<std::string> &file2) {

    assert(file1.size() <= file2.size());
    std::vector<std::string> file3(file1.size());
    std::string temp;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < file1.size(); i++) {
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < file1[i].size(); x++) {
            int enc = 0;
            if (file2[i].size() <= file1[i].size()) {
                for (unsigned int t = 0; t < file2[i].size(); t++) {
                    enc = (int)file1[i][x] + (int)file2[i][t];
                }
            }
            else if (file2[i].size() > file1[i].size()) {
                enc = (int)file1[i][x] + (int)file2[i][x];
            }

            if (enc > 126) {
                file3[i] += (enc % 127);
            }
            else {
                file3[i] += (enc + 32);
            }
        }
    }
    return file3;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::string> a{ "1", "2", "3" };
    std::vector<std::string> b{ "6", "7", "8" };

    for (const auto& s : a)
        std::cout << s << std::endl;

    for (const auto& s : b)
        std::cout << s << std::endl;

    auto c = Encode(a, b);
    for (const auto& s : c)
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `the strings are immutable`: no, `std::string` are mutable

Comment: Why would you `assert(file1.size() <= file2.size())`? is `Encode` only supposed to work under that condition? That seems like a terrible idea. How about you make the algorithm work if `file1.size() > file2.size()`, and throw out that `assert`.

Comment: @quantdev sorry, yes std::string are mutable, fixed, to many languages in mind

Comment: the assert is for checking in runtime in debug, if that conditions holds, according to the sample code and the code in my response, if **file1.size() > file2.size()**, when executing the line `if (file2[i].size() <= file1[i].size()) {` you will be indexing file2 out of bound for some index. This case need to be handled or indicate that can not happen (design restriction perhaps), the assert could be used in cases when the condition checked could not happen (and if happen you want to known it)